# Sending e-mail via lua nginx timeout error

Tags: email, nginx, lua, server

I'm trying to send e-mail via lua+nginx.

Lapis (Lua) code

```
local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
app:get("/ee", function(self)

    local from = "<mail0@mydns.name>"
    local rcpt =  {
      "<mail1@gmail.com>"
    }

    local mesgt = {
      headers = {
        to = "PP <mail1@gmail.com>",
        cc = '"V.V." <mail2@gmail.com>',
        subject = "My first message"
      },
      body = "I hope this works. If it does, I can send you another 1000 copies."
    }


    local r, e = smtp.send{
      from = from,
      rcpt = rcpt, 
      source = smtp.message(mesgt),
      server = "127.0.0.1", 
      port = 25
    }

    return  "R:" .. tostring(r) .. "  E: " .. tostring(e)
end)
```

gives timeout error (after several seconds passed): `"R: nil E: timeout"`

Nginx config is:

```
http{
      server{
        listen 9000;
        location = /cgi-bin/nginxauth.cgi {
            add_header Auth-Status OK;
            add_header Auth-Server 127.0.0.1;  # backend ip
            add_header Auth-Port   25;        # backend port
            return 200;
        }
    }

}

mail {
    auth_http         localhost:9000/cgi-bin/nginxauth.cgi;

   server {
        server_name     mydns.name;
        listen          25;
        protocol        smtp;
        proxy           on;
        timeout 5s;
        proxy_pass_error_message on;
        #smtp_auth       login plain;
        xclient         on;
        smtp_auth none;
    }
}
```

I do not understand the core of mail server. How to configure?  How to use nginx server? I think timeout error appears due to mail-server just redirect but doesnt process email data, am I right? Or what have I do to fix with error?